# Safe way to work in Git

Tags: git, github

I have Git installed on my unix server and have my webapps directory containing my entire web-site contents which I have set up as a non-bare repo.

There are 2 other members in my team who also work on web-site stuff.

How can we 3 developers work in the same non-bare repo and commit our changes without having any risk of committing other developers files which may happen if I do `git add .` and then commit them?

Can anyone suggest a safe method for 3 or more people working in this scenario?

Comment: Each dev should work in a separate repo.

Comment: If we work in a separate repo then how can we test our changes as and when we change them say a jsp file coz the tomcat would be pointing to the original webapps directory

Comment: Update the live repository in that case. So first commit locally, after that sync it all to the repository of the web-server.

Comment: It is supposed that each dev has its own environment, including tomcat so they can work independently not stepping on each other feet. And there is a production environment there you update all files then it is ready to be published.

Comment: @Argeman:Right.But for me to test my single line change in say a html file I have to commit it to the live repo right.Then if that dosent work it will stay in the live repo as buggy code.And several developers will be pulling from that repo who will get my buggy code.Any way I can test without causing mayhem.Any suggestions?

Comment: @kan:I'm still talking about dev environment the production environment still is not in picture.We have a single dev server which is a unix server where tomcat is installed and which points to the webapps directory. There is only one instance of tomcat running.I did not get what you were suggesting.

Comment: @DarkMatter No, the other developers do not just fetch everything from the live testing system, only the things that really matter. You can create a testing branch for that tiny change, push that tiny branch to your testing environment, check that branch out on the live test system and switch back to the released branch afterwards. You can then delete the whole branch afterwards if you don't like it.

Comment: I use git, and manage the release process for my software. Though I do not understand about websites, is it not possible to commit locally, test this local repo, and then push to remote only if everything is okay? This is how I do it for my software, though I do not know if it works for websites.

Comment: @DarkMatter: That's the problem. A single dev environment, when there are 3 developers, is wrong. Each developer should have his own repo, hios own Tomcat, and his own database. That way, each developer tests in his own environment, and when everything is OK, he pushed to the central bare repo.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want two developers sharing a working copy. There's no way to ensure safety in this case: what if both of you go to edit the same file at the same time?

`git` has plenty of tools for merge-conflict management, but *none* of them will help you if you have two devs sharing a single repository for their works-in-progress.

Instead, set things up so that each dev has their own testing environment, where they can evaluate whether changes made to their local copy are functional. When a change is ready for "release", they push it to a central shared repository. The code in that central repository eventually makes its way out to the production environment.

The web servers the developers use to test their changes probably don't have to be anything fancy; for example, Python has a built-in tiny web server that can be invoked via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. This or a similar small server is likely fine for testing HTML and Javascript projects. If you have a more complex setup, you can still stand up a "staging" copy for each developer: duplicate your database, your web server, and so on. If you want to go all out, have each dev work on a cloned virtual machine with a complete duplicate of your live environment.

If you want a really strong guarantee that code entering the main repository is good, use a gatekeeper system like [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) and/or an autobuilder like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). For a three-person team, it's probably sufficient to just have each dev double-check their own changes before they push them out.

If you **must** share a working copy, you're going to have to fall back to an older system: CVS-style locks. Before a developer makes a change to a file, they need to "check it out". While it's "checked out", no other developer can touch it (make it read-only). Before anybody makes a commit, you yell across to your coworkers to say "hey, I'm making a commit! Nobody else do anything!". Then you do a `git add -i` or similar, make the commit and then tell everybody else it's all clear and they can proceed. **This is a bad way to work**. Don't do it.

Comment: :How can anyone run more than one instance of a java -ee website in a server where tomcat is installed.

Comment: @david.colais You can either run two containers, or have one container host two instances of the site.

Comment: :How can one container host two versions of the site.Isn't thw work directory which has the jsp class files going to conflict between the two sites and what about the server.xml which needs to be different coz the other site will be punning on a different port compared to the original website.

Comment: Is there a way in git to do cvs style locks for files in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a bare repository which is used to update the live webapp and then either setup a test environment (either separate tomcat installation or virtual domain) for each developer or have the developers edit a non-live install of the webapp.

In either case the work flow would look something like this from the developer's perspective:

```
$ cd ~/webapp
$ git add file.html
$ git commit -m "Updating file to perform task."
$ git push origin
$ cd /path/to/production/webapp
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge origin/testbranch
```

The flow is a little longer than just using one working copy of the web app, however this allows each developer to use Git to its full capabilities.  If all of the developers are sharing the same working copy, you may as well just using a file by file revision control system like RCS.